# Split Range by other Range between it? VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, named-ranges

Let's say i got the Range B1:BF1

And another, Variable Range (i.E E1:W1)

I want to split the Upper with the lower one, so the Result would look like that

B1:D1, X1:BF1

Is it possible to save a split-up range like that in one Variable?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have to do some reversed `Intersect` operation. Unfortunately I don't know of any of such operation.

Hereby a small piece of code that will check the ranges and see where they overlap. If they don't overlap it will create a new range.

```
Sub Test()

Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, Rng3 As Range, Cl As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set Rng1 = .Range("B1:BF1")
    Set Rng2 = .Range("E1:W1")
    For Each Cl In Rng1
        If Intersect(Rng2, Cl) Is Nothing Then
            If Not Rng3 Is Nothing Then
                Set Rng3 = Union(Rng3, Cl)
            Else
                Set Rng3 = Cl
            End If
        End If
    Next Cl

Debug.Print Rng3.Address
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

I hope that gets you started.